# jquery tooltip not working

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm trying to use a jquery tooltip to create an image that follows the mouse around once it enters a specific div. (the iris and pupil should follow the cursor inside of the eyeball div, link below) I have seen lots of tutorials on tooltips and similar tools, but they are more complicated than what I need. Finally i found this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/HHKgZ/86/
that is exactly what I need. However, when I applied it to my css/ html, it didn't work!
here's what I have: 
http://jsfiddle.net/vYk8h/4/

Is there something that's preventing it from working? or is the code wrong? (I'm new to javascript) Should I instead be using the mouseenter/ mouseleave function?
any input is welcome,
thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:

```
left: e.pageX 0,
top: e.pageY 0
```

to:

```
left: e.pageX + 0,
top: e.pageY + 0
```

Or some value other than zero, depending on how you're trying to position.